# Automatically open the breadcrumb control with Bing Maps V8 Web Control

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

With [Bing Maps V8 Web Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712542.aspx), we have the ability to show a breadcrumb control. In the [MapOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712646.aspx) we set to `true` the option named `showBreadcrumb`.

By default it will be closed and it appears like this:

[image: Bing Maps V8 Web Control Breadcrumb control closed]

However I'd like to see it open like this:

[image: Bing Maps V8 Web Control Breadcrumb control opened]

Is there any option to have it open by default or a way to programmatically open it?

Side note: I noticed the user preference for the breadcrumb is saved. If it is open once, when the map control is reloaded, the breadcrumb will automatically appear open, meaning the opened/closed state is internally managed by the map control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to have it fully open by default.

The breadcrumb feature is actually a very expensive feature as it does a reverse geocode call every time the map is moved. Majority of users completely ignore it. As such doesn't fully open unless a user selects it open, this way only users who actually want it, use it. This feature was nearly removed altogether in V8 as it was only added to Bing maps V7 as it was needed for Venue maps which are now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Ricky, I understand your point. In the scenario in which I use it, the breadcrumb is really convenient, I guess it's better if I reverse geocode with Bing Maps REST Services as I want to display the name for only one location.